# New York Comic Con 2012, October 12-14

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

**UPDATE:** All 3-day passes have been claimed. Thank you to everyone who claimed a pass. See you at the con!

---

[New York Comic Con](http://www.newyorkcomiccon.com/) is soon approaching (October 12-14). For any users interested in attending, Stack Exchange has 3-day passes available. Please note that **Stack Exchange is only providing 3-day passes**; **we are not responsible for travel or lodging**.

Those receiving a 3-day pass will get a Stack Exchange NYCC swag package, including a SciFi.SE shirt, stickers and lanyard to use at the con and, also, your day-to-day existence

For a pass, please e-mail the following information to **brett [at] stackexchange [dot] com** with the title **NYCC 2012**:

1. Your name
2. Your username
3. Your mailing address
4. Your t-shirt size

**There are only 10 3-day passes available, and this offer is also being extended to [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/). If you want one, don't wait!**

Stack Exchange will also have a booth on the show floor this year (Booth #2278). Employees from the Community Growth team and other departments will be at the booth, and our **[famous (?) Spinning Wheel](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/heroescon-2012-report/)** will also be distributing prizes to all who spin it.

Thanks!

Comment: Curse you atlantic ocean!

Comment: How was it? Could we expect to see a blog post or something?